# Apply the same set of CSS classes to multiple elements using sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox, responsive-design, css-grid

I am creating a responsive HTML page and have to apply the following classes to multiple elements ( around 50 divs ) in the HTML page. Is there a way to apply the same set of classes to multiple elements instead of repeating the same code 50 times. I am using sass. The classes I want to apply are :

```
class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 ml-0"
```

I have tried using grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(360px, 1fr)); but find it inefficient to use .px. Is there any other alternative to achieve a responsive design ( maybe using flexbox).

EDIT:

My HTML is something like this.

```
<div class="mb-4 contact-info">
 <p class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 ml-0">
  <span>aaa</span>
  <span>bbb</span>
 </p>
 <p class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 ml-0">
  <span>ccc</span>
  <span>ddd</span>
 </p>
 <p class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 ml-0">
  <span>eee</span>
  <span>fff</span>
 </p>
 <p class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 ml-0">
  <span>ggg</span>
  <span>hhh</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will add the same styles to each row in your table:

```
table tr {
  @extend .row;
  @extend .row-cols-1;
  @extend .row-cols-md-2;
  @extend .ml-0;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @mwi I have added a small part of my HTML code to the mail question. I am actually not using tables, just a combination of Divs and Ps. Thanks for your help